# Measure Theory "Incompleteness"

Tags: measure-theory

So, i have been studying some measure theory , and from what i was introduced we can have sets that are jordan-mensurable and lebesgue-mensurable. In both of these cases we can find sets that we cant classify, we cant give a measure to, if we use the axiom of choice in the case of lebesgue. My question is, is it possible to create a theory that can classify in terms of measure to every set? That can complete lebesgue-measure? Or is it just impossible?(can we prove that is impossible?). Keep in mind im thinking of a theory that can work with the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you want all the "reasonable" properties of a measure to hold. You should look up the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: Can we prove it, i mean that if we have a set of the properties we want we can never achieve it ? Im guessing the vitali set uses them all right?

Comment: Yes, if i remember correctly the Vitali set shows that you cannot define a measure $\mu$ on all subsets of the real line such that $\mu$ is translationally invariant, sigma additive, and $\mu([a,b]) = b-a$. You can find it in most books on measure theory, I think.

Comment: Alright ,Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what properties you want your measure to have.  You can define "outer" measure for every set, and it agrees with Lebesgue measure for measureable sets, but it's not additive for all sets.  In fact you can pretty much define Lebesgue measurable sets as the ones for which outer measure behaves additively.

You can also define inner measure, and a bounded set is Lebesgue measurable if and only if its outer and inner measures are equal.

If you want a true measure (countably additive) that assigns a finite measure to every bounded set and a non-zero measure to every open interval, it's certainly possible, but it won't be translation invariant.  For example, define a measure that assigns measure $\frac{1}{q^3}$ to each rational with denominator $q$ and to any set the sum of the measures of the rationals in that set.

As for why the axiom of choice guarantees that any translation-invariant countably-additive measure must make some sets non-measurable, look up "Vitali set" in Wikipedia.

It may also be worth noting that even without the axiom of choice, the contiuum hypothesis implies the existence of non-Lebesgue-measurable sets, as see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191262/sierpinskis-construction-of-a-non-measurable-set , so to get a set theory with all sets Lebesgue measurable requires that both the axiom of choice and the continuum hypothesis fail.

Comment: I mean the ideal thing would be to be additive yes.

Comment: Moved my reply into answer.